# Why I get error when fit with `@` in Host?

Tags: domain, cname

I want to add a `@` CNAME points to an alias in Godaddy.

You see I write `@` in Host, but it still say I was wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with this particular control panel layout, but it seems to me you misunderstand hiw CNAMES work (a common misconception)

A CNAME is not an alias, it redelegates authority for that  and all subdomains and records at the same level  (including NS records).

The take-away is you can only use CNAMES on subdomains.

A CNAME for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is OK  but example.com is not.

Comment: Your conclusion is right, but the explanation is wrong. CNAME does nothing for subdomains, and does nothing for authority delegation. It is an alias because it causes the client to look up the same records under a completely different name – the target does _not_ become authoritative for the original name, unlike with NS where the target server is still queried for the original name and does become authoritative for it.

Comment: ("A CNAME RR identifies its owner name as an alias, and
specifies the corresponding canonical name in the RDATA section of the
RR.  If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be
present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases
cannot be different.")

Comment: @user1686 if I have a subdomain a.b.example.com with an A record, and an mx record for b.example.com  and b.mydomain.com is a cname to b.example.com, a.b.mydomain.com will resolve to the A record for a.b.example.com and b.mydomain.com will have an MX record that matches b.example.com.   If I gave an NS recird for b.mydomain.com it will be ignored.

Comment: "a.b.mydomain.com will resolve to the A record for a.b.example.com" no it won't. (I tried several times to make sure. If it did they wouldn't have had to invent DNAME...) "b.mydomain.com will have an MX record that matches b.example.com" not quite how it works. (The query will return the MX record of b.example.com, sure...but if you look at the answer section, that record will be *under the name of b.example.com*. The original b.mydomain.com name will still show just a CNAME. This is entirely different from NS delegation, which restarts at a different server but keeps the same name.)